# Gesture Detector and SingleChildScrollView Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I was trying to create a scroll view and add a gesture detector to find the exact location of the screen.
The gesture Detection shows location of the blue Container which is correct because its the child, but it shows the pixel position relative to the phone. I want to see the pixel position relative to the full screen(body). That means the blue Container starts after (10,000 pixels). Any help would be appreciated.
My code:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.redAccent[200],
              height: 1000.0,
              width:  500.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details){
                print("Start");
                print(details);
              },
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent[200],
              height: 1000.0,
              width:  500.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Also Why is the `SingleChildScrollView`Not working on the blue side?

Image of Screen[image: Screen - if I touch the red Container I can scroll but Can't if I swipe using the blue]

Image of output of Gesture Detector [image: This gives me the position where I click on the blue Screen it gives me the position as (323.1, 523.1) I want to get it as somewhere around 1000 for height, but it doesn't take the red Container to the position]

Comment: please consider inserting an image what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry my bad. I added the images, I hope you understand it. I'm not good at explaining :(

Comment: The `DragStartDetails` consists of `localPosition` & `globalPosition`. Please take a look at those properties.

Comment: This Worked! I don't know how to set the comment as an answer tho.